# how to create variable dynamically and pass into php built in function

Tags: php

I have a string like this: `$shortName = 'DATE,FB,DS,AK,GB,AJ,GL';`

Now I want to create variables like `$DATE $FB $DS $AK $GB $AJ $GL` dynamically for passing these variables into `bind_result()` function.

**here is my code**

```
$gameQuery  = "SELECT `SHORT` FROM `game` WHERE `STATUS` = 1"
$gameStmt   =  $this->game->prepare($gameQuery);
$gameStmt   -> execute();
$gameStmt   -> bind_result($short);

$shortName = 'DATE';

while ($gameStmt->fetch()) {
   $shortName = $shortName.','.$short; 
}

echo $shortName; #output : DATE,FB,DS,AK,GB,AJ,GL

$chartQuery = "SELECT $shortName FROM `chart` WHERE MONTH(`date`) = ?";
$chartStmt  =  $this->chart->prepare($chartQuery);
$chartStmt  -> bind_param("s",$month);
$chartStmt  -> execute();
$chartStmt  -> bind_result();
```

Does anybody have a solution or an alternative for this ?

Comment: sorry but how ? `$shortName` store every `$short` and after while loop end i am using in other query ..

Comment: sorry my bad , any solution ?

Comment: *any solution ?* See the answers below maybe they answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to do this:

```
$vars = explode(',', $shortName);
$array = array_combine($vars, $vars);
extract($vars);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/312078)</kbd>

`explode()` turn that string in an array using the comma as a separator. `array_combine()` creates an associative array with keys (needed for the next step). Then `extract()` turns each array element into a variable.

This feels convoluted but it is what you asked for.

Comment: Sorry but how can i use this variables in `bind_result()` function ?